# Not able to send mail using YiiMailer

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

I am trying to send a mail using YiiMailer Extension, when I used Port 465 getting error "fwrite(): send of 16 bytes failed with errno=10054 An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" and when I used port 587 its fails to send a mail.

Code:
In controller:

```
            $mail = new YiiMailer();
            $mail->setData(array('message' => 'Message to send', 'name' => 'John Doe', 'description' => 'Contact form', 'mail' => $mail));
            $mail->setFrom('abc@gmail.com', 'John Doe');
            $mail->setTo($_POST['UserLogin']['email']);
            $mail->setSubject('Reser Password');
            $mail->setBody('Simple message');
            $mail->IsSMTP();
            $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            $mail->Port = 465;
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
            $mail->Username = "*******@gmail.com";
            $mail->Password = "********";
            if ($mail->send()) {
                Yii::app()->user->setFlash('contact','Thank you for contacting us. We will respond to you as soon as possible.');
                Yii::log("Mail sent");
            } else {
                Yii::app()->user->setFlash('error','Error while sending email: '.$mail->getError());
                Yii::log("Mail Error");
            }
             }
```

In main.php

```
 'import'=>array(
    'application.models.*',
    'application.components.*',
            'ext.YiiMailer.YiiMailer',
),
```

Please help me to come out of this problem and I tried other extension too like Emailer, PHPMailer but there i got some SMTP error "smtp unable to connect to the remote server"

Thanks in advance

Comment: set the port as 587 and try.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you do not have `php_openssl` enabled in your server's `php.ini`. Check `phpinfo()` to make sure you have it enabled.

Also you may need to add the lines

```
$mail->SMTPSecure='ssl';
$mail->Mailer='smtps';
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me!

```
  $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        $mail->Port = 587;
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->SMTPSecure= 'tls';
        $mail->Username = "*******@gmail.com";
        $mail->Password = "********";
```